# Lightswitch: cannot fill form

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

I followed tutorial here
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2010/08/23/lightswitch-beta1-now-available-building-your-first-app.aspx#comments

The form runs but I cannot fill it ! Why ?

Update: There's no error message I just can't enter the field to type anything: it's read-only

Update 2: I ask the gurus on Microsoft Forum, they tried to answer hard, nobody can find out why. Seems beta is very beta :)

Weirdly I did have this problem on a windows 7 PC not on a Windows 2008 pc

Comment: Error message? Compiler error? Anything beyond "it doesn't work" ?

Comment: There's no error message I just can't enter the field to type anything: it's read-only

Comment: Do you have a link to your conversation on the MS forum? Some more information would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried this in beta 2? Are you still seeing the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try these,

1) Have you selected the `Editable Grid Screen` ? 
2) Is there any add new icon on the top right corner of grid screen you can click to add new items into?